# Obtener el valor enviado de un primer formulario y mostrarlo en otro

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript

Tengo mi `form` donde registro datos de usuario con los campos nombre y  apellido y funciona perfectamente; también tengo otro `form` con los mismos campos para que me reciba los datos e igualmente funciona. Ahora, en ese mismo `form` también tengo una etiqueta `<h4>` donde quiero que me aparezca el dato enviado (`nombre`) de mi primer formulario, pero no me aparece. No sé qué me falta. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Quiero que aparezca aquí:

```
<p></p>
<h4></h4>
```

Éste es mi primer formulario de registro:
Con este codigo envio mis datos..(si funciona.. si envia)

```
sendUserCliente(id, value) {
  this.authService.getById(id).subscribe(res => {
    this.userGet = res;
    const cliente = new Cliente(value.firstName);
    console.log(cliente);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/cliente/carga/detalle-de-carga');
  }, err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  empresa: [
    null,
    Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(40)])
  ],
})
```

**Primer formulario**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm"   (ngSubmit)="myForm.valid && sendForm(myForm.value)
                    " novalidate class="form-horizontal">  
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input
              type="text"
              id="firstName"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Nombre"
              formControlName="firstName"
        >
    </div>
</form>
```

**Segundo formulario**

Éste es mi segundo formulario donde recibo los datos del primer formulario,
pero en mi `h4` no me aparece el dato registrado en el primer formulario.

```
    <form [formGroup]="myForm"   (ngSubmit)="myForm.valid && customerUpdateForm(myForm.value)" novalidate class="signup-ademia-formulario-general">
     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input
              type="text"
              id="firstName"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Nombre"
              formControlName="firstName"
        >
    </div>
</form>
<h4 id="firstName"></h4>
```

Con este código recibo los datos del primer formulario

```
customerUpdateForm(value: Object): void {       

    const user = new User(
        this.myForm.value.email,
        this.myForm.value.password,
        this.myForm.value.firstName,        );

this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            empresa: [null , Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(40)])],
        },)  
    }
```

Este es el codigo que uso para ambos y me funciona ok ya que registro y recibo los datos. Ahora quiero que el dato de `firstName` me aparezca en el `h4` pero no me aparece, no sé qué código debería poner.

Comment: ¿en que momento quieres que aparezca? ¿el escribir?, ¿al dar click en un botón? falta más información

Comment: @ReneLimon disculpen es la primera vez que publico en esta web...!!  no se explicarme biien....cuando me registro mis datos se guardan normal en mi base de datos....!!ahora  en un input text he logrado que mis datos de registro aparescan.... ahora quiero que tbm me aparescan en una etiqueta label o en un "h4" pero eso no se como hacerlo

Comment: ¿Estás usando Angular 2?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía si uso MEAN (Mongodb Express Angular y Nodejs)

Comment: No se si lo he entendido bien, pero lo que tu quieres es simplemente que te muestre el nombre? entonces haz esto: <h4>{{firstName}}</h4>

Comment: <h4>{{myForm.get('firstName').value}}</h4>

Answer (score 0):

Veo algunos errores bastante básicos si estás usando angular 2.

Para empezar en tu `<h4 id="firstName"></h4>` No estás indicando nada que angular pueda interpretar como que ahí va un valor. Es decir, debes pasarle el valor o bien mediante ngModule o bien con las etiquetas {{firstName}}.

Por otro lado, estaría bien que especificaras si los formularios están en la misma página html o en componentes distintos. Ya que si están en componentes diferentes necesitarás usar `@Input` y `@Output` para pasar el valor.

Si amplias un poco más la información quizás pueda ayudarte. A parte me gustaría ver el input text donde dices que has conseguido mostrar el valor, si es posible.

Un saludo!

Comment: Hola. También es posible pasar los datos a través de un servicio.